# Remove context menu item from Firefox

Tags: firefox, context-menu

Is there a way to remove the context menu items in Firefox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Menu Wizzard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/) Firefox add-on allows you to rearrange or remove menu items from the main context menu (right-click menu) and main menu bar (*File*, *Edit*, *View* etc.).

There were also [Menu Editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/710) and [Menu Editor II](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/menu-editor-ii/) Firefox's extension available to the market some time ago, but they are now both gone. First is gone completely and the development's of second one is ceased.